# Compare Data in Two Separate Excel Worksheets - Conditional Format

Tags: excel, if-statement, formatting, conditional-statements

BLUF: I need to highlight email addresses if they're not found in the official roster.

**Scenario**: I have an excel file with two spreadsheets, sheet1, and sheet2.

Sheet1 is a list of a bunch of users:  FullName, Email

Sheet2 is a list of our employees: FName, LName, Email

"Email" values are formatted the same on both sheets

So, what I'm hoping to do is Highlight anything on Sheet1 that's NOT on Sheet2.

**Pseudo-solution**: (Not Working)

- Highlight all "Email" Values in Sheet1
- Conditional Formatting > Use a formula to determine which cells to Format (Format Fill = yellow)
- Use an "IF" statement: =IF(!$D$2:$D$200=Sheet2!$D$2:$D$2000,"True","False")

**Expected Result**:

- Sheet1 "Email" values will be highlighted if they're not found on the larger Sheet2 "Email" table

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming on Sheet1 the Email is in column B, and sheet2 email is in column C.

In Sheet1, highlight B1 (the first email) and go to Conditional Formatting.  The formula you can use is `=Countif(Sheet2!$C:$C,A1)=0` then choose a highlighting/format you want.  Then, set the range for that formatting to your desired range.  Does this make sense? Please let me know if I can clarify anything!

The formula will look at cell A1, then look in Column C on Sheet 2.  If the name in A1 exists in the Sheet2 range, the COUNTIF formula will be 1 (or greater, depending on number of times it appears).  If there is NO match, COUNTIF returns 0 - and this will then highlight all the cells where the formula returns 0.

Edit: Here's some screenshots if they help.

Here's my sheet 2 table (all in Column A, starting A1):

```
Batman
Wonder Woman
Ghandi
Robin
Dr. Manhattan
```

and in Sheet1, I have (again, starting A1):

```
Superman
Batman
Dr. Manhattan
Señor Velociraptor
```

Select Sheet1, cell A1, and put this conditional formatting:
[image]

Then, you can change the range of the formatting to match what you need:

[image]

and there you go!

Comment: Absolutely brilliant!  Your solution was exactly what I was looking for, and you broke it down "Barney-style" with the screen caps.  Thank you!

Comment: Ah - if you want to apply the Conditional Formatting to the Range $A:$A (so you don't have to always get the last row), you will notice that even blank cells turn red.  To fix that, change the Conditional Formatting formula to: `=AND(A1<>"",COUNTIF(SEARCH!$A:$A,A1)=0)`.